# not Working ScrollView and HorizontalListView

Tags: android, scrollview

Can some one help my with ScrolView in Android Mobile App.My problem- on my  vertical ScrollView i have horizontal "hlistview»,and when i moved "hlistview" up/down/right/left play only one. How they can work together? At time,work only one.

```
hListView.setOnTouchListener(new HorizontalListView.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should only disallow the parent view if you're scrolling in the direction you want. You need to save the last Y or X and set a threashold. If you reach that threashold that means you're scrolling horizontaly/verticaly and it's safe to disallow the parent

Comment: You should not use ScrollView and ListView in one layout. The ListView takes care of it´s own scrolling. And I guess the HorizontalListView extends a listView, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nested scrollviews you must intercept the touch events. However if you just `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` on ACTION_DOWN you are making the it's parent disable touch events the moment your finger touches the screen. That's not the wanted behavior. You need to set a threshold and only disallow the events the moment your scroll distance has hit that threshold.

On the nested scrollview ACTION_DOWN set a field saving the initial X (for horizontal swipe) like this:

```
mLastX = event.getX();
```

Next on ACTION_MOVE compare it with your threshold (50 in this example)

```
if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mLastX) > 50)
          requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```